# Prove an inequality in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Let  $ p,q \in \mathbb{R}, \; \lambda > 0, p \neq q$ (two points).
 For the two points $x_+, x_{-}$ with 
\begin{align*}
x_+&=p+\lambda\cdot (q-p)\\
x_{-}&=p-\lambda \cdot (q-p)
\end{align*}
I have to prove:
$$|\;\!  x_+-q \!\;| < |x_--q|$$
I started with
\begin{align*}
|x_+-q|&=|p+\lambda\cdot(q-p)-q|\\
&=|p-q|+|\lambda\cdot (q-p)|\\
|x_{-}-q|&=|p-\lambda \cdot (q-p)-q|\\
&=|p-q|-|\lambda \cdot (q-p)|
\end{align*}

It's quit understanding, why $|x_+-q| < |x_--q|$ holds, but I'm definitely not sure, if my "proof" is finished at this point. In particular I don't know if $<$ is already prooved.

Comment: sorry, I forgot: $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, it's the common euclidean metric

Comment: You should not use $d (X_+, Q) =|X+−Q|$ unless it's stated that $X_+$ and $Q$ are real subsets.

Comment: ok, changed it, and I think I should mention, that we have $\mathbb{R}^1$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$ or something "higher"

Comment: I think, it's $q \in Q$ and $p \in P$.

Comment: @ulead86 I edited your post, look if it is still the same problem

Comment: By the way the last equal signs are wrong, the absolute value is not linear you only have the triangle inequality

Comment: Yes, you're right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align*}
|x_+ -q|&= |p+\lambda(q-p)-q|\\
&=|p(1-\lambda ) - q( 1-\lambda)|\\
&=|(p-q)\cdot (1-\lambda)|\\
&=|p-q|\cdot |1-\lambda|
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
|x_- -q|&= |p-\lambda (q-p) -q|\\
&=|p(1+\lambda) - (1+\lambda)q|\\
&=|p-q|\cdot |1+\lambda|
\end{align*}
We know that 
$$ |x_--q|> |x_+-q| \iff |x_--q|-|x_+-q|>0$$
and 
\begin{align*}
|x_--q|-|x_+-q|&=|p-q|\cdot |1+\lambda|-|p-q|\cdot |1-\lambda|\\
&=|p-q|\cdot (|1+\lambda|-|1-\lambda|)
\end{align*}

As $p\neq q$ we have $|p-q|>0$ hence we only need to prove that 
$$|1+\lambda|-|1-\lambda|>0$$
when $0<\lambda \leq 1$ we have
$$|1+\lambda|-|1-\lambda|=1+\lambda - 1 +\lambda = 2 \lambda > 0$$
When $\lambda >1 $ we have 
$$|1+\lambda|-|1-\lambda|=1+\lambda +1-\lambda=2 >0$$
Hence $$|x_--q|>|x_+-q|$$

Comment: excellent idea and great job (under my bad instructions)...

Answer (score -3):

This result is true for any metric space, whether it's Euclidean or not (or, may be not, according to a comment below).

The initial form of the question, didn't demand the sets to be Euclidean, so is my proof focused on earlier version of the question.
My take was something like this:

$d(x_+,q)=d(p+λ(q−p),q)=d(p,q)+ d(λ(q−p),q) \\ =d(p,q) -d(\lambda (q-p),q)+2d(\lambda (q-p),q) \\ =d(p-\lambda(q-p), q)+ 2d(\lambda (q-p),q) \\ =d(x_-,q) +2d(\lambda (q-p),q)$

here,  $x_−=p−λ(q−p)$

(( I used, $d(x\pm z,y) = d(x,y)\pm d(z,y)$))

As $2d(\lambda (q-p),q) \gt 0$  $ \forall p\neq q$ and $\lambda \gt 0$

We have, $d(x_+, q) \gt d(x_-, q) $
$\Box$

Comment: Nope it is not true in general, take the metric space $(M,d)$ with $M:=\{\mathrm{monkey},\mathrm{pinguin}\}$ and the discrete metric. Now try to add a monkey and a pinguin.

Comment: Even if $+$ is defined $d(x+y,z)=d(x,z)+d(y,z)$ doesn't hold, in fact it doesn't even hold in the euclidiean metric. Take $z=0$ $x=-y\neq 0$ and you get infinit many counter examples